# File field label

Tags: 7, files

I have created a custom content type that has a file field.  When I upload a file the node displays the complete file name, test_file.pdf. I would rather display its file name as clickable link. I have tried manage display and set the format to URL to file and it displays "File: site_name.com/sites/default/files/test.txt," which is only text.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Are you using the development snapshot of Drupal 7? I am using Drupal 7, but for a file field I can only select "File," as widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track! Go to "Manage Display" and set the format to "Generic File", it will give you a clickable filename with a link to the file!

Comment: I am using that now and it's ok but I am looking for 'cleaner' look where the node displays the field label "File" and a link like "Download" rather than the file name, file.txt for example.  Hope I am being clear with what I am trying to accomplish.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok now I see, as far as I know you can't do that out of the box. You can either create a new formatter (probably kinda complicated) or just override the template for that kind of node (either using contemplate or plain .tpl.php)

Comment: @LandonAB Under the arrow to down vote, there is a check mark. I cannot see it in this question, as it has been asked by you, but that is the place where to look at. You should see [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/bzQAH.png).

Answer (score 3):

I've created a module on drupal.org that provides a formatter that does just that: https://www.drupal.org/project/file_formatters.

Comment: Sweet!  I subscribed to it on drupal.org, anticipating a 7.x version.